# Divide Circle into three parts using CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on circle I want circle divide into 3 part like attached image [image]

Each part will be clickable, I am using HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery, is it possible to divide circle into 3 parts?

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 430px;
  height: 430px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(15deg);
  padding-top: 20px;
}
li:first-child {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:first-child .text {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(2) .text {
  background: tomato;
}
li:nth-child(3) .text {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<ul class="circle">
  <li>
    <div class="text">1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text">3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you post the jQuery/javascript please? Will make answering it much easier. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry dude, There is only css3 with html5.. @AgataB

Comment: not idea svg, can you show or how to use svg in my scenario

Comment: you can check out this pens and see if it helps
[pen1](http://codepen.io/Mirel/pen/bVNaEj),
[pen2](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/JdjpNW)

Answer (score 5):

Hope this snippet helps you a little bit. Maybe try the hover with jQuery.

```css
.circle-outer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 430px;
  height: 430px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 580px;
  height: 580px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: -70px;
  top: -95px;
}
li {
  
}
li .background {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
.content .icon {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #000;
}
.content.first {
  left: 15%;
  top: 30%;
}
.content.second {
  right: 15%;
  top: 30%
}
.content.third {
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 32%
}
li:first-child .background {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:nth-child(2) .background {
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:nth-child(3) .background {
  transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:first-child .background {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(2) .background {
  background: tomato;
}
li:nth-child(3) .background {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="circle-outer">

  <ul class="circle">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content first">
          <div class="icon">
            <div class="fa fa-search"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content second">
          <div class="icon">
            <div class="fa fa-search"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
        <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content third">
          <div class="icon">
            <div class="fa fa-search"></div>
          </div>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect @MarcosPérezGude, only problem in Safari, I added -webkit- in all class but no luck

Answer (score 3):

Check my answer:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 430px;
  height: 430px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  right: -20%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(15deg);
  padding-top: 20px;
}
li:first-child {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(30deg);
}
li:first-child .text {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(2) .text {
  background: tomato;
}
li:nth-child(3) .text {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<ul class="circle">
  <li>
    <div class="text">1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text">3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you @eronax59 for your support, worked great! only problem it is not showing good in Safari