# How can I accomplish these type of round buttons using HTML / CSS / JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, button

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is several buttons aligned like a circle. It is supposed to be circular although it looks like an egg. I hope the image makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Stack Overflow isn't a free coding or design service. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: SVG is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It's not super easy but you can do it. You would basically do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641653/divide-circle-into-three-parts-using-css3#38658351) only you overlay another circle on the centre.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way here is to use svg.

Take a look here:

```css
svg{width:170px}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<path fill="red" d="M 13.3974 50 A 100 100 0 0 1 186.6025 50 L 143.3012 75 A 50 50 0 0 0 56.6987 75 Z"></path>
<path fill="blue" d="M 186.6025 50 A 100 100 0 0 1 100 200 L 100 150 A 50 50 0 0 0 143.3012 75 Z"></path>
<path fill="green" d="M 100 200 A 100 100 0 0 1 13.3974 50 L 56.6987 75 A 50 50 0 0 0 100 150 Z"></path>
<g dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
<path id="btn1" d="M 62.5 35.048 A 75 75 0 0 1 137.5 35.048" fill="transparent" />
<path id="btn2" d="M 175 100 A 75 75 0 0 1 137.5 164.9519" fill="transparent" />
<path id="btn3" d="M 62.5 164.9519 A 75 75 0 0 1 25 100" fill="transparent" />
<text>
  <textPath startOffset="50%"  xlink:href="#btn1">
    Button 1
  </textPath>
</text>
<text>
  <textPath startOffset="50%"  xlink:href="#btn2">
    Button 2
  </textPath>
</text>
<text>
  <textPath startOffset="50%"  xlink:href="#btn3">
    Button 3
  </textPath>
</text>
</g>
<text x="100" y="100" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="black">Hello world!</text>
</svg>
```

You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) about svg path, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Texts#textPath) about text path.

For calculating the `x` and `y` of the points on the circle, note that `x = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius` and `y = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * radius`.

For example, at the example above the viewportis 200*200, so `centerX = 100, centerY = 100`, with outer radius 100, and inner radius 50. the top part going from angle `-5*Math.PI/3`, so the x point is `100 + Math.cos(-5*Math.PI/3)*100 = 13.3974` and y point is `100 + Math.sin(-5*Math.PI/3)*100 = 50` and so on